# ASP.NET MVC is it okay to work with the ApplicationUser model for account management?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I know that each time a user registers in my ASP.NET MVC application the ApplicationUser class is used to create the new record and put it in the database.

I was wondering if it's okay to add properties to that class for example I want the model to have a column in the database for DateOfBirth. Then use that class(model) directly in my application when I have to do some business logic things, database queries and similar stuff. Or is it more correct to create a new table in the database called let's say ApplicationAccounts, that saves the general info about the account. Each ApplicationAccount will be associated with a ApplicationUser(1 to 1 relation) and be somewhat of a buffer in the communication with the real accounts. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second option : create your own table, link them up in a one to one relationship using the UserID as a unique foreign key and then go from there.

One note here, it is perfectly normal for the model you need for the views to be different from the database model, this is because your db model can hold a lot of data that your view doesn't actually need. You might want to consider having separate models and use something like Automapper for a quick translation from one to another.